# Run String in Text Box (containing Mid and InStrRev functions) as Code in VB NET

Tags: string, vb.net, text, expression

I have searched high and low and do not think this is a duplicate question as all the examples I found do not have functions (mid, InstrRev etc.) embedded in them.

I have a form containing 3 text boxes (tbFName, tbFNameExpression, tbFNameResult).

tbFName.Text contains an example filename and can be changed by the end user:

> P05-158-4J-RM-001-REV-1.xlsx

tbFNameExpression.Text contains a string (which can be changed by the end user) I wish to run as code:

> Mid(tbFName.Text , InStrRev(tbFName.Text , "-REV") + 1, 5)

This should populate tbFNameRev.Text with the Revision from the example document name.

> REV-1

Obviously the text values can be changed by the end user, depending on what information is required in tbFNResult.

For example, if tbFNameExpression.Text = "Left(tbFName.Text,3)" then tbFNameResult should = "P05"

I have tried the following:

```
Dim strFNExpression As String = tbFNameExpression.Text
        tbFNameResult.Text = New DataTable().Compute(strFNExpression, Nothing)
```

But this returns the error:
"The expression contains undefined function call Mid()."

I also tried a function using CodeDom to process an expression from here:
https://www.theswamp.org/index.php?topic=33503.0

Comment: No easy way to do this. You might be better off using regexes

Answer (score 0):

No easy way to do this. You can try regexes:

```
tbFName.Text = "P05-158-4J-RM-001-REV-1.xlsx" 'Want to extract "REV-1"
tbFNameExpression.Text = "REV-."
tbFNameResult.Text = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(tbFName.Text, tbFNameExpression.Text).Value
```

Comment: Thanks @SSS, that does answer my problem here.

Comment: That's a great idea I hadn't thought of.  I have used (?!-)REV(?=\.) as the expression to return what I want.  I haven't marked your answer as 'the' answer yet as I am still hopeful someone will reply with how to run my string as code.

Comment: Glad it was helpful. Happy programming!